# how to collide SKSpriteNode with SKLabelNode? SKSprite

Tags: swift, collision-detection, skspritenode

I guess I am pretty clear in question... The case is that I am trying to collide SKSpriteNode which is a basket with SKLabelNode which is the word. Actually I can detect collision between my basket with the wall but when I apply the same rule to label and basket. I couldn't detect a collision.

Here is the code I create word
'''

```
func createWord() {    
    words = SKLabelNode(text: "\(wordBank[wordIndex])")
    words?.physicsBody! = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: self.size)
    words?.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = wallCategory
    words?.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = wallCategory
    words?.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = wallCategory
    words?.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    words?.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
    words?.fontSize = 20
    words?.name = "words"

    let number = Int.random(in: 1 ..< 10)
    words?.position = CGPoint(x: (50 * number), y: 450)
    words?.zPosition = 1
    addChild(words ?? SKLabelNode(text: ""))
}
```

'''

Here is the code I create basket

"""

```
    basketNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "basket.png")
    basketNode.size = CGSize(width: 106.03, height: 100)

    defaultBasketPos = CGPoint(x:frame.midX, y:basketNode.frame.height/2)
    basketNode.position = defaultBasketPos
    basketNode.name = "basket"
    basketNode.zPosition = 1

    basketNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: basketNode.size)

    basketNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = wallCategory
    basketNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = wallCategory
    basketNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = wallCategory
    basketNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    basketNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    addChild(basketNode)
```

"""

I just print("collision") to func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)

and finally here is the code I

'''

```
 let wallCategory:UInt32  = 0x1 << 1
```

'''

I guess I made a mistake in here because the problem is that I couldn't understand categories well.

Thanks!

Comment: The size of the physicsBody for words seems to be wrongly set to `self.size` - did you mean to set it to `words.frame.size`?